# stream get total record count and assign back to object

Tags: java

I have two records, but how can I get the total record count back into the object:

**Input**

> 1, Kelvin
> 1, Kelvin
> 2, Advin

**Output**

> 1, Kelvin, 2
> 2, Advin, 1

```
        final int total = 0;
        Map<String, PersonModel> map = persons.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(f -> f.getCode() + f.getName()
            (s, a) -> new PersonModel(
                s.Code(),
                total + 1
            )));
```

The total I get is still 1.

Comment: Can you show some sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: @Sweeper added the sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key here is to use correct Equals and Hashcode method to identify If PersonModel already exists based on code and name attributes.

```
class PersonModel {
    private int code;
    private String name;
    private int count;

    //setters getters

    public PersonModel(int code, String name) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        PersonModel that = (PersonModel) o;
        return code == that.code &&
                Objects.equal(name, that.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(code, name);
    }
}
```

//code

```
List<PersonModel> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    persons.add(new PersonModel(1,"Kelvin"));
    persons.add(new PersonModel(1,"Kelvin"));
    persons.add(new PersonModel(1,"Kelvin"));
    persons.add(new PersonModel(2,"Advin"));
    persons.add(new PersonModel(2,"Advin"));

    Map<Integer, PersonModel> dataWithTotal = persons.stream().map(personModel -> {
        personModel.setCount(1);
        return personModel;
    }).collect(Collectors.toMap(person -> person.getCode(), Function.identity(),
            (p1, p2) -> {
                p1.setCount(p1.getCount() + 1);
                return p1;
            }));
//dataWithTotal will have code 1 with total =3 and code 2 with total=2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```java
List<Input> inputs = Arrays.asList(
        new Input(1, "Kelvin"),
        new Input(1, "Kelvin"),
        new Input(2, "Advin"));

List<Output> results = inputs.stream().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()),
        map -> map.entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> new Output(e.getKey().getNum(),
                                     e.getKey().getName(),
                                     e.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
        ));
System.out.println(results); // [(1, Kelvin, 2), (2, Advin, 1)]
```

```java
class Input {
    private final int num;
    private final String name;
    public Input(int num, String name) {
        this.num = num;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getNum() {
        return this.num;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.num;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (obj instanceof Input && this.num == ((Input) obj).num);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + this.num + ", " + this.name + ")";
    }
}
```

```java
class Output {
    private final int num;
    private final String name;
    private final long count;
    public Output(int num, String name, long count) {
        this.num = num;
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + this.num + ", " + this.name + ", " + this.count + ")";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following example by replacing Pair with your Person class.

```
import java.util.*;
import javafx.util.Pair;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<Pair<Integer,String>> persons = new ArrayList();
        persons.add(new Pair(1,"Kelvin"));
        persons.add(new Pair(1,"Kelvin"));
        persons.add(new Pair(2,"Advin"));
       
        Map<Pair<Integer,String>, Integer> map = persons.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(f -> f, f -> 1, Integer::sum));
          
        System.out.println(map);
 
    }
}
```